# Incorrect datetime value: '%2014-08-08%' for column 'added_on' at row 1

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to filter a `DateTimeField` comparing with a date as follows

```
import datetime  

product_list.filter(added_on__contains=datetime.date(2014, 8, 8))
```

This throws a warning

```
Warning at /specs/filter/
Incorrect datetime value: '%2014-08-08%' for column 'added_on' at row 1
```

What woudl be the correct way to do this?

Comment: @ruddra That returns an empty set. I was using contains because the `DateTimeField` also has the time attached to it and I'm just passing it the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this that I can think of at the top of my head.

1. You could get creative with the `__range` filter and use datetime objects from the start of the day to the end of the day.
2. Use `gte` and `lte`
3. What I would personally use is a chain of date filters from the most granular to the least as I love being able to understand my code at first glance:

> product_list.filter(added_on__year=2014).filter(added_on__month=8).filter(added_on__day=8)

and let django do the optimization.

Comment: I ended up using the chain of date filters. It's a shame that such a basic functionality is so hard to implement in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Well `contains` work for text input(string type) of django models, so using `contains` in datetime field will end up throwing error. So you have to filter either like:

```
product_list.filter(added_on=datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 8, 16, 12, 30))
```

or like     `product_list.filter(last_updated__gte=datetime.date(2014,7,8)).filter(last_updated__lte=datetime.date(2014,7,10))`